# Turbo C Database in Notepad

Tags: c++, c, database, notepad, turbo-c++

I'm working on a case study by myself - a Japanese to English Dictionary Using Turbo C and notepad.

Relevant part of my code:

```
#‎include‬ <stdio.h> 
main() 
{ 
    FILE *a; 
    char word[20], ans[1]; 
    clrscr(); 
    a=fopen("dictionary.dbf","a"); 
    do 
    { 
        printf("Add a word: "); 
        scanf("%s",&word); 
        fprintf(a,"%s \n",word);
        printf("Add another one? (Y/N)"); 
        scanf("%s",ans);
    }while(strcmp(ans,"y")==0); 
    fclose(a); 
}
```

This code enables me to insert a word from TC to and saves it Notepad. Unfortunately, I don't know how to print a certain word from Notepad then display it to TC.

I need a little help from you guys.
This is my case study, and I do my case study without having a group.

Comment: ans is of size 1, How are you going to store a c type string in there but an empty string, you need storage room to store Y or N in there? This way it is an nice example of a not so nice buffer overflow security problem. `Y` would need two bytes { 'Y','\0'} and make sure your `%s` can not read as many characters as it likes.

Comment: As far as i know scanning string using `%s` doesn't require `&` in scanf statement.

Answer (score 1):

Just few easy steps.

1. Your notepad is a file so open that file by `fopen(const char *
   filename, const char * mode)`.
2. When you open the file read the file by `fread(void * ptr, size_t
   size, size_t count, FILE * stream)`
3. Now final step... Print that on console or anywhere you want, You
   can use `fwrite(const void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE *
   stream)` for that operation.

I hope will help you to write the code. do not forget to apply all error checks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    char buf[100];
    FILE *a;
    a=fopen("dictionary.dbf","r");

    while (!feof(a))
    {
      fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), a);
      printf ("%s",buf);
    }

    fclose(a);
```